# How to load Java in Oracle Database using SQL Developer?

Tags: java, oracle

I'm running Oracle 19.

I would like to load some Java classes using SQL Developer, but the option is greyed out.

Is there any necessary grants to do that? Or is there any other way to do it via SQL Developer?

[image]

Comment: Have you [enabled Java in the database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/installation-and-configuration.html#GUID-D4659736-30EB-4810-ADA0-F2D8E1BE4F77)?

Comment: What is the result of this query? `SELECT dbms_java.get_jdk_version FROM dual;` Does the user you are connected as have the privilege to `CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE`?

Comment: Did you install the Java utilities? I assume they are not included in SQL Developer installation.